# Automatically highlight data that appears in worksheet

Tags: excel, compare, pivot-table, highlight

I have two different Excel spreadsheets that contain the pricelists of two different manufacturers. I need Excel to highlight the items in the pricelists that occur in both pricelists (Reason: to be able to quickly find the items that both manufacturers offer and who offers it at the best price. The lists are EXTREMELY long hence doing it manually won't work!).

I have searched for two days online to find a solution to this problem but nothing helped. I found one site that offered a code to create a macro, which I tried, but unfortunately only returned an error.

Can anyone give me a solution like a formula that I can simply copy?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the details in a PivotTable then you could compare prices where both manufacturers supply the same item and otherwise see which does and its price:

[image: SO18379097 example]